# In the weak formulation of the Poisson equation, why is the boundary condition included in the integration of the weighted residual?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-element-method, poissons-equation

In the weak formulation of the Poisson equation $\nabla^2u = g$ with boundary conditions $u = \bar{u}$ on $\Gamma_e$ and $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{n}} = \bar{q}$ on $\Gamma_n$, why is the integration of the weighted residual expressed as 
$$I = \int_\Omega w(\nabla^2u-g) d\Omega - \int_{\Gamma_e} w\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{n}}d\Gamma$$ and not just
$$I = \int_\Omega w(\nabla^2u-g) d\Omega$$

Comment: Ignore weights for now. If you do that, you multiply by a test function and "formally" integrate the DE itself by parts. You get $\int_\Omega -\nabla u \cdot \nabla v dx + \int_{\Gamma_e} v \nabla u \cdot n d \Gamma + \int_{\Gamma_n} v \nabla u \cdot n d \Gamma$. in the last term. You enforce the Neumann condition on the weak form by just replacing $\nabla u \cdot n$ with $\overline{q}$. You enforce the Dirichlet condition on the weak form by restricting to those $u \in H^1$ with $u=\overline{u}$ on $\Gamma_e$.

Comment: To avoid making the problem inconsistent, you then additionally require that the test functions $v$ will vanish on $\Gamma_e$. Now we say that $u \in H^1$ is a solution if $u=\overline{u}$ on $\Gamma_e$ and $\int_\Omega -\nabla u \cdot \nabla v dx + \int_{\Gamma_n} v \overline{q} d \Gamma = \int_\Omega g v dx$ for all $v \in H^1$ which vanish on $\Gamma_e$. You can check that a strong solution is a weak solution and a smooth weak solution is a strong solution, basically by undoing the integration by parts.

Comment: @Ian Why not post an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring weights, multiply both sides of the original DE by a test function and "formally" integrate by parts. You get

$$\int_\Omega -\nabla u \cdot \nabla v dx + \int_{\Gamma_e} v \nabla u \cdot n d \Gamma + \int_{\Gamma_n} v \nabla u \cdot n d \Gamma = \int_\Omega g v dx.$$

Now we apply the boundary conditions in the weak form. On the Neumann part of the boundary $\Gamma_n$, we just replace $\nabla u \cdot n$ by what it should be. It turns out that you're stuck with this seemingly weird approach. That's because in the appropriate space of candidate solutions, restricting solution functions to the boundary makes sense but restricting their *derivatives* to the boundary does not.

By contrast, the approach on the Dirichlet part of the boundary is what you would expect. We restrict our solution space to functions which satisfy our Dirichlet condition. To do this without making the problem inconsistent, we must also restrict our test functions to those which vanish on $\Gamma_e$. A nice way of thinking about this is that in the associated variational problem, test functions are the directions in which we can move in the space of possible solutions. If we go in a direction which doesn't vanish on $\Gamma_e$, then our new function doesn't vanish on $\Gamma_e$, so it should not be a candidate for the minimizer in the variational problem.

Thus the weak formulation of the problem says: $u$ is a solution if $u \in H^1$, $u=\overline{u}$ on $\Gamma_e$, and

$$\int_\Omega -\nabla u \cdot \nabla v dx + \int_{\Gamma_n} v \overline{q} d \Gamma = \int_\Omega g v dx$$

for all $v \in H^1$ which vanish on $\Gamma_e$. The manipulations we did in the first place imply that a strong solution is a weak solution. Undoing the manipulations that we did shows that a smooth weak solution is a strong solution. Thus the weak formulation correctly corresponds to the strong formulation.

If you need weights, you can do it again analogously (provided the integration by parts still makes sense with the weights).

Comment: There we go with that "formally" business again.  I think you are the same person a few weeks ago that answered something about the dirac delta function and said "formally".  Can you explain again what "formally" means?  It doesn't mean actually formally.  Does it mean intuitively?  Does it mean the opposite of formally?  Is that why there are quotations?

Comment: I'm thinking that the "formally" stuff is probably some mathematical standard that I haven't been exposed to.  That's why I'm asking you about it again.

Comment: Nice comment.  But what do we mean when we write "formally" while writing math.  Can you express "formally" in other words.  How should it be thought of/read?

Comment: @user46944 For PDE purposes, if $u$ were a strong solution, then the DE would make sense and we could just integrate by parts. But we now want to define what a weak solution is. The most basic two properties that it should have are that a strong solution is a weak solution, and a smooth weak solution should be a strong solution.

Comment: @user46944 In distribution theory in general, certain definitions get motivated by a density argument. For instance, if $f$ is a distribution and $\phi_n$ are smooth functions which converge in the distributional topology to $f$, then it is natural to define $f'=\lim \phi_n'$. Most of these "formal" definitions in distribution theory work this way.

Comment: But you just did it again.  You used "formal".  I want to know what that means.  Look, in topology when we say the words "all of the points nearby", we interpret this language as "all of the points in *some* open set".  Every piece of language in math has an interpretation.  I am simply asking you what the interpretation is of writing the phrase: "formally" (in quotes).  Please express "formally" in alternate words so I know what it means.

Comment: You used it here, and you used it a few weeks ago in the dirac delta question.  When you write "formally" in an answer, you *mean* something, just as if I wrote "all of the nearby points" in a topology answer, I would mean "all of the points in some open set".  When **you** write "formally", what do **you** mean?  After all, if you are writing it, then you expect the reader to know what you mean.  And I don't.  But I want to.

Comment: @user46944 In distribution theory, "formal" manipulations amount to an interchange of limits: for instance if $f$ is a distribution and $f_n$ is a sequence of test functions converging in the distributional topology to $f$, then $f'=\lim f_n'$.

Comment: @user46944 For this to make proper sense, you should show that it does not depend on the approximating sequence. The way you want to do that is to write $\langle f_n',\phi \rangle$ as $\langle f_n,\psi \rangle$ for some appropriately selected test function $\psi$. Then $\langle f_n,\psi \rangle \to \langle f,\psi \rangle$ by definition, so this defines $\langle f',\phi \rangle$. In a similar fashion we *define* the distributional Laplacian on the whole space as well as the distributional Laplacian on bounded domains with sufficiently smooth boundary that the divergence theorem holds.

Comment: @user46944 But this is specific to distribution theory. There are various other usages in physics of terms like "formal limit" which are not the same. So I am not sure how to give a truly satisfactory, general answer to this question.

Comment: So basically there is no nice translation of the phrase: "formally" (in quotes).  Unlike in my topology example in the previous comments, to me there is no clear and simple translation, and so it doesn't make sense to me. :(

Comment: @user46944 Instead of getting stuck on the language, just follow the mathematics that results from it. In distribution theory we *define* the derivative of a distribution through $\langle f',\phi \rangle = \langle f,-\phi' \rangle$. Similarly we *define* the Laplacian of a distribution on a "nice" domain $\Omega$ through $\int_\Omega \Delta u v dx = \int_\Omega -\nabla u \cdot \nabla v dx + \int_\Gamma v \nabla u \cdot n dS$.

Comment: I do understand what you've written.  But it's the language I'm trying to interpret.  I hate the idea that there is some language out there that other people are using and understand, and I should understand it because I come across it, but I don't.  If you told me right now to write my own answer and use the phrase "formally" (with quotes), I wouldn't know what to do.

Comment: @user46944 The important thing is that both of these definitions are consistent with the classical definitions (where $f$ resp. $u$ are smooth). The "formal manipulation" is basically this consistency check.

Comment: So when you write "formally", you really mean something along the lines of "we have the following, which we expect to have if we were in a classical context".

Comment: @user46944 In the context of distribution theory that is absolutely correct. Also relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152034/usage-of-the-word-formally

Comment: Let me return to your dirac delta answer and make sure I see that that is what you were saying there, too.